# Why -NotMatch is not working while using within a PowerShell script?

Tags: string, powershell, pattern-matching

I have one XML file. I want to search for a string and then delete that line from the file.

Now the problem is that when I run following code from PS console, it works fine - deletes the line which contains "test3". But when I put the same code inside a PS script and run it, it is NOT deleting the intended line. Can you please let me know if I am missing something?

test.txt:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
```

Code:

```
$loc = "D:\test.txt"
$msg = "test3"
$newF = Get-Content -Path $loc | where {$_ -notmatch $msg}
$newF
```

I am using PSVersion: 5.1.14393.1358.

Comment: I don't think this quite makes sense. Are you sure that even this example code exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: @Briantist - I agree, however, I believe that OP is thinking that the final line of code (`$newF`) should delete the line in the file, as opposed to displaying the output.  suv3ndu, please confirm.

Comment: Ah, good call @gravity .

Comment: I ran this code with no issues in PowerShell and in a script file.  Could you describe specifically what happens in your case, OP?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this behavior. $newF outputs the file contents omitting test3.

Comment: Thanks for checking! Let me grab the screenshot so that I can show you the problem I am facing. Also I noticed that if I use a hard coded value(test3) instead of $msg, it is ommiting the line. That is why I got puzzled.

Comment: I found that it was a problem in my script. In my original script, I was dynamically assigning value to a variable like this: 
`code` $msg = "some_text" + $num

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I found that it was a problem in my script. In my original script, I was dynamically assigning value to a variable like this: 
$msg = "some_text" + $num

Now for that, one extra space was getting added and as expected -notmatch was not working. So I added trim() and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

Works absolutely fine. See the picture below.

Works fine from the console also.

Answer (score 0):

`-notmatch` is designed to work with a regex.  I'd suggest using `-notlike` in the future.  As others have stated, your limited example is not reproducible.

Doc on `-notmatch`: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#-notmatch)